# Can Puppet .pp files themselves be .erb templates?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I want the sites defined in `nodes.pp` to come from a .yml file. I'm thinking if the .pp file is itself processed first from an .erb file then this would be easy. But as far as I can tell the .pp files cannot be templates themselves, eg. `nodes.pp.erb`.

I want to keep the nodes definition in yml rather than in .pp because I want to use the same definition for things like vagrant test of deployment. I find it easier to consume a common .yml rather than parse nodes.pp to extract the info.

the obvious solution is to generate nodes.pp on-demand from a nodes.pp.erb, eg. in a rake task, but I wonder if Puppet itself has a solution to my conundrum.

Answer (score 1):

I think puppet hiera would work well for you, check out:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera#readme

Comment: thanks, is a bit more than I thought but looks like it would work. I'll give it a try.